# Distribution of linear combinations multivariate normal

Tags: self-study, distributions, expected-value, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose $Y$ ~ $N_{3}(\mu,\sum)$

Let $ \mu=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1   \\
    4 \\
    8
  \end{bmatrix}$
and 
$ \sum=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1  \\
    1 & 8 & 2  \\
    1 & 2 & 6
  \end{bmatrix}$

Let $X=3Y_{1}-4Y_{2}+Y_{3}$

What is the distribution of $X$? I know it reduces to a scalar but I am not quite sure exactly how to compute the matrix operations to get there.